# Using functors in generic class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write poor man's version of the stl set container, but I'm not very capable with templates. My version is declared as such:

```
template <class T, class comp>
class set
{
...
}
```

When I use the comp functor directly, everything seems to compile fine, but when I try to pass it further to actual stl functions like so:

```
void set_method(const T &elem)
{
        lower = lower_bound(internal.begin(), internal.end(), elem, comp);
}
```

I get some nasty errors along the lines of `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token`. Is there a way to do such thing, or something with similar effect, or do I have to implement everything to use the comp functor directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comp` is a type parameter, which means `comp` denotes a type, not an object.  `lower_bound` expects a function object, not a type of a function object, so you get an error.  To "convert" the type into an object you need

```
lower = lower_bound(internal.begin(), internal.end(), elem, comp{});
```

Where `comp{}` creates an object of type `comp`.

Otherwise what you can do is make a `comp` member in your set like

```
template <class T, class comp>
class set
{
private:
    comp cmp{};
    // ...
public:
    set(comp cmp) : cmp(cmp)
    // ...
    void set_method(const T &elem)
    {
        auto lower = lower_bound(internal.begin(), internal.end(), elem, cmp);
    }
};
```